# want to add content encode in RSS Parser Library code

Tags: php, codeigniter, rss, encode, rss-reader

I'm using CodeIgniter and RSS Parser Library. I'm ok with this code.

> function get_ars()  {
>       // Load RSS Parser
>       $this->load->library('rssparser');
>
> ```
> // Get 6 items from arstechnica
> $rss = $this->rssparser->set_feed_url('http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/index/')->set_cache_life(30)->getFeed(6);
>
> foreach ($rss as $item)
> {
>     echo $item['title'];
>     echo $item['description'];
> } }
> ```

but i want to add more for content encode. but i don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found Solution at http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/2007/01/07/using-simplexml-to-parse-rss-feeds/
Open application/libraries/Rssparser.php.
Go to Line Number 107
Add Follwing Statement.

```
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$content = $item->children($ns['content']);
$data['content'] = (string) trim($content->encoded);
```

And You may use

```
echo $item['content'];
```

in your View file.